# How to fill default parameters in yaml file using python

Tags: python, yaml

I have a YAML file with content:

```
       image_name: ubuntu
       components:
                 image_name: ubuntu
                 image_flavors: [medium, large]
                 image_ip : 192.168.12.134
                 imageuser : ubuntu
                 image_pass : ubuntu
                 image_config: /home/ubuntu/
                 image_net_type: vlan 
                 image_switch_type: ovs
```

I have implemented a script for this to load YAML file and o/p I have got in dict format.

```
       with open("test.yaml", "r") as input:
        try:
            a = yaml.safe_load(input)
            print "Parsing YAML file is completed"
            print a
        except yaml.YAMLError as error:
            print(error)
```

my dict format as below:

```
{'image_name': 'ubuntu', 'components': {'image_ip': '192.168.12.134', 
 'image_pass': 'ubuntu', 'image_switch_type': 'ovs', 'imageuser': 'ubuntu',
 'image_name': 'ubuntu', 'image_flavors': ['medium', 'large'], 
 'image_net_type': 'vlan', 'image_config': '/home/ubuntu/'}}
```

How I can fill default parameters if any key has no values?

Comment: Your YAML file has keys for its mappings, and your Python dictionary has keys as well. Please edit your post to make clear which of the two you want to use as default parameter for the other.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, do you mean something like this:

```
default_values = {
    'image_name': 'some',
    'components': {
         'image_ip': '192.168.1.1',
         'image_pass': 'default_password',
         'image_switch_type': 'ovs',
         'imageuser': 'default_user',
         'image_name': 'default_name',
         'image_flavors': ['medium', 'large'],
         'image_net_type': 'vlan',
         'image_config': '/default/home/'
     }
}

def setdefault_recursively(tgt, default = default_values):
    for k in default:
        if isinstance(default[k], dict): # if the current item is a dict,
            # expand it recursively
            setdefault_recursively(tgt.setdefault(k, {}), default[k])
        else:
            # ... otherwise simply set a default value if it's not set before
            tgt.setdefault(k, default[k])

dic = { 'image_name': 'ubuntu', 'components': { 'image_name': 'ubuntu' }

setdefault_recursively(dic)
```

?

This should fill your `dic` read from yaml file with default values, recursively:

```
{'components': {'image_config': '/default/home/',
            'image_flavors': ['medium', 'large'],
            'image_ip': '192.168.1.1',
            'image_name': 'ubuntu',
            'image_net_type': 'vlan',
            'image_pass': 'default_password',
            'image_switch_type': 'ovs',
            'imageuser': 'default_user'},
 'image_name': 'ubuntu'}
```

That is, all settings within the structure which weren't explicitly set from the YAML file, have received their default values from `default_values`, uhmm, recursively.

Comment: hello,the above func is useful but looks like  some what complex.Can you please elaborate it.i am not able to understand your logic

Answer (score 3):

One option is when you are getting a value for a key in the dict that was parsed from the yaml, use the `get()` method of the dict. so

```
value = a.get('key', 'default')
```

If the key `key` is in `a` it will return the value else it will return whatever you specify as the default. In the above e.g that would be `'default'`